# NullReferenceException in System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Schedule when using System.Net.WebClient

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, webclient, nullreferenceexception

I posted [another post](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/38538/xamarin-bug-please-have-a-look-at-my-code-example#latest) with the same issue. There is a simple Xamarin solution on github that you can download and run [here](https://github.com/frel/DemoApp). Please do.

It seems that calling `System.Net.WebClient.DownloadDataTaskAsync` in DEBUG mode on my Xperia Z3 (it works just fine with an emulator) the first time throws a `NullReferenceException` in `System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Schedule`:

```
    public async Task<String> DownloadString(String url)
    {
        if (UseAuth)
            webclient.Headers.Set("Authorization", TokenType + " " + AccessToken);
        else if (!UseAuth && webclient.Headers["Authorization"] != null)
            webclient.Headers.Remove("Authorization");
        String response = "";

        try
        {
            byte[] data = await webclient.DownloadDataTaskAsync(url);
            response = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);
        }
        catch (WebException e)
        {
            response = new StreamReader (e.Response.GetResponseStream ()).ReadToEnd ();
            ErrorResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ErrorResponse> (response, settings);

            if (ErrorResponse.Error.Status == 401 && ErrorResponse.Error.Message == "The access token expired") {
                Console.WriteLine ("Error: " + ErrorResponse.Error.Status + " - " + ErrorResponse.Error.Message);
            }
        }
        return response;
    }
```

This code solves the problem, but I think it's a dirty fix and it doesn't really address the underlying problem.

```
public async Task<String> DownloadString(String url)
    {
        if (UseAuth)
            webclient.Headers.Set("Authorization", TokenType + " " + AccessToken);
        else if (!UseAuth && webclient.Headers["Authorization"] != null)
            webclient.Headers.Remove("Authorization");
        String response = "";

        var failCount = 2;
        for (int i = 0; i <= failCount; i++) 
        {
            try
            {
                byte[] data = await webclient.DownloadDataTaskAsync(url);
                response = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);
            }
            catch (WebException e)
            {
                if (i == failCount) 
                {
                    response = new StreamReader(e.Response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();

                    ErrorResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ErrorResponse>(response, settings);

                    if (ErrorResponse.Error.Status == 401 && ErrorResponse.Error.Message == "The access token expired") 
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine ("Error: " + ErrorResponse.Error.Status + " - " + ErrorResponse.Error.Message);
                    }
                    // Break out of the loop
                    break;
                }
            }

        }

        return response;
    }
```

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Schedule (Boolean
>   throwException) [0x00000] in :0 at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Start
>   (System.Threading.Tasks.TaskScheduler scheduler) [0x00000]  in :0 at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory.StartNew[WebRequest] (System.Func1
>   function, CancellationToken cancellationToken, TaskCreationOptions
>   creationOptions, System.Threading.Tasks.TaskScheduler scheduler)
>   [0x00000] in :0    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory.StartNew[WebRequest] (System.Func1
>   function) [0x00000]  in :0 at System.Net.WebClient.SetupRequestAsync
>   (System.Uri address) [0x00000]  in :0 at
>   System.Net.WebClient+c__async0.MoveNext () [0x00000]  in :0 --- End of
>   inner exception stack trace --- at
>   System.Net.WebClient+c__async0.MoveNext () [0x00000]  in :0 --- End of
>   stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw ()
>   [0x00000] in :0 at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[System.Byte[]].GetResult
>   () [0x00000] in :0 at
>   SpotifyWebAPI.SpotifyWebAPIClass+c__async1A.MoveNext () [0x00133]
>   System.Net.WebException

Here is a screenshot from Xamarin Studio

[image]

The problem *only* happens with my device and DEBUG build mode. In RELEASE it works perfectly and on the emulator it works on both DEBUG and RELEASE.

As stated in the original post, calling  `System.WebClient.DownloadDataTaskAsync` a second, third or Nth time all result in normal behaviour. It also only occur when I use a Spotify Android SDK Java binding project and call `OpenLoginWindow()` (which opens another activity, logs in and returns successfully) prior to calling `DownloadDataTaskAsync`.

Comment: Please post smallest possible sample that demonstrates the problem inline in the post. Otherwise this post likely be closed as duplicate of "What is NRE and how to fix it", which unlikely to help you.

Comment: I am not sure how I can do that. The sample I have provided is the one that crashes. I am not sure how to reproduce it. Marking this as a duplicate of "What is NRE and how to fix it" is just an insult, and really unhelpful. The NRE happens after another activity has started and finishedWithResult, so it is vital to the case.

Comment: I ran your project, and no matter what configuration, I get an "Error: could not contact Spotify. Is a network available?" toast message.  Was I supposed to see something different?

Comment: Hi, @SharpMobileCode thank you for helping out. Did you run it on a device or emulator? Did it have a working network connection? You should be able to log in to spotify without any problems before there is an issue.

Comment: I was running it on the emulator with a network connection, but it must be a firewall issue.  I can run it on my phone just fine now.  I do not get the error you described above on my phone.  The app start up with a loading progress dialog, and then I see the Spotify login activity. I have a OnePlus One running Android 5.0.2.  This is in Debug and Release.

Comment: @SharpMobileCode So after you log in and you press "Send request" it does not print "Error: Exception trying to retrieve profile: ..." in the application output (console)? It prints your user name the first time? Are you using the newest version of Xamarin and the libraries? Thanks for helping

Comment: Ah okay, I can re-create the issue you are describing. After logging in, the Send Request failed the first time, but is successful after that. I'll have to look at this later on when I have more time. But at first glance, any reason why you're using WebClient as opposed to HttpClient or ModernHttpClient? I'll look at this later this evening.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75864/discussion-between-fred-larsen-and-sharpmobilecode).